# Reverse value from one view to another by using protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Now I'm learing the swift programming and I'm stuck on the protocol grammar.

There's a simple function I want to implement: There are two ViewControllers I've created in one Main.Storyboard, The first ViewController has a label and a button to go to the second ViewController. The second one has a textField and a button to go back to the first ViewController.

I entered some words in the textField and click go-back button to dismiss the view, but I can't see the label changed on the first view.

Here's what I've coded for the delegate view:

```
import UIKit

protocol SecondViewDelegate {
    func getText(text: String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var text: String?
    var delegate: SecondViewDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
//        print(text!)
        delegate?.getText(text: text!)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
//        print("textFieldDidEndEditing has been called")
        text = textField.text
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
}
```

I've print the text when I pressed the backButton and I'm sure the text printed on console is which what I entered in the textField.

And here's the code for another view which showed the text:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let secondVC = SecondViewController()
        secondVC.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func clickButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecond", sender: self)
    }

    func getText(text: String) {
        self.textLabel.text = text
    }

}
```

When I returned to the view, the label didn't change. And I added a breakpoint in the function getText and run the app, the app didn't crash.

I don't know which part I've done wrong. Can anyone point out the problem to help me? Thanks!

Comment: The issue is you create another `SecondViewController` here:
`let secondVC = SecondViewController()`

It is not your view controller from the storyboard.

Keshu R. gave you the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first view controller, if you are using segues to go to second view controller, you need to set the `delegates` in `prepareForSegue` method. Currently you are creating a new object in `viewDidLoad` and assigning it the delegate, which is wrong.

Here is the solution:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func clickButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecond", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToSecond" {
            if let vc = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
                vc.delegate = self 
            }
        }
    }

    func getText(text: String) {
        self.textLabel.text = text
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add this method to your code for pass delegate.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToSecond" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            vc.delegate = self 
        }
    }
}
```

And remove this lines of code.

```
let secondVC = SecondViewController()
secondVC.delegate = self
```